# multiple svg images in one file breaks text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have a web app that uses SVG files to map various sorts of data onto our underlying experimental dataset. Each SVG file represents a mapping of one type of data to the experimental dataset and, in most of the pages on the site, they are displayed one at a time, with the various nodes carrying tooltips to make the maps more informative and links to associated data.

I would like to add a page where maps can be compared side-by-side, which means having multiple self-contained SVG's all on the same page. When I do this, however, the files seem to step on each others' toes in that only the first SVG on the page displays the correct text in the labels and axes. The rest appear to inherit the alphabet used in the first image, leaving the axes and labels garbled and nonsensical.

The snippet below shows how I am currently embedding the SVG's in the page. The object blocks are loaded up with SVG content via javascript/ajax when the user chooses a map on a dropdown menu. Everything functions correctly except for the noted problem with the SVG text.

```
<object id="map" name="map" class="compBuild" width=800 height=460></object>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("change", ".db_field", function(e) {
    var tmp = this.name.split("_");
    var field = "map_" + tmp[1];
    $(document.getElementById(field)).load(getSvgUrl($(this).val()));
    // getSvgUrl just makes a Jquery AJAX call to obtain the location of
    // the SVG file.
})
```

Maybe not obvious from the code given, but what actually happens on the page is that the menus and object blocks are dynamically generated, so the actual drop-downs and object blocks are addressed as mapSelect_X map_X, where X is a number appended when the block is created. (code not shown for the sake of brevity!)

I am wondering if there is a workaround for this as I would rather not convert the SVG files to images, since I would lose the functionality in the SVG's. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: where's the code that loads the objects?

Comment: I've added the Javascript to the original message.

Comment: SVG's are not html. I think that is your problem when you treat them like html using ajax.

Comment: All the AJAX call is doing is supplying the location of the file, which is served as static XML content by the web server. See the answer below for what turns out to be the root of the problem: apparently the SVG is considered part of the overall document, not as a discrete entity, so the the fact that there was overlap between `id` attributes in the symbols' definitions was at issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that there are no duplicate `id` attributes in the two SVGs.  `id`s must be unique on the page, otherwise any SVG features that use id references (like `<use>`, gradients etc) can't be trusted to point to the right thing.

Since Chrome and FF handle duplicate ids differently, a quick way to check this is the cause would be to see if the two browsers render the two-svg page differently.

Comment: This makes sense. I just compared two of the files and the text character definitions are assigned id's in each file, following the same convention: id="glyph0-1", ..., id="glyph0-N". I guess the XML standard does not treat the SVG files as separate images but as part of the overall DOM? I would not have guessed this but I guess it makes sense and is probably the "right" thing to do! Anyway, knowing that this is the case, I think I should be able to reassign those id's to make sure they're unique to each file. Here's hoping...

Comment: Eureka! All it took was appending a random integer to each symbol's id and all is well. Thanks a million for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You are using `$().load()` to import the SVG files into the page.  So the SVG contents are becoming part of the page DOM.  That's why the uniqueness of the ids matter.